# Loading page time with and w/o ads

Tags: seo, ads, page-load-time

Certain page with AddThis, Facebook like box, adsene, plusone and analytics takes 6.45 secs to load according gtmetrix.com

Same page without ads loads in 1.23 secs.

In the first page all ads are loaded after relevant data is displayed to the user.

For SEO do I care about?

Is it possible to reduce ads loading time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should care, yes you can do something about it...

Comment: Make sure you're using the asynchronous versions of the scripts where possible. Here's a good solution for like g+ etc. - http://www.phpied.com/social-button-bffs/